# How to use "Create Undead" without any risk?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, undead, saving-throw

My party has recently slain a [Linnorm](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/dragons/linnorm/) Dragon and we would very much like to [raise](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/create-undead/) it as a [Juju Zombie](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/zombie-juju-cr-1/), thus having something really hard to kill as a frontline. The problem is that if the caster doesn't control it, we just unleashed in the world something we hardly can stop, due all the resistances as Juju zombie and Dragon type.

So, I was wondering if there is any way to debuff the Will save of the corpse-that-will-soon-be-undead. (Keep in mind that Linnorm Dragons are immune to curses.)

As for the source material, we are using the PF Core, Advanced Player's Guide and Ultimate Magic and Combat.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome! You can take the [tour] as an introduction to the site and check the [help] for further guidance. Although the title question states "without any risk", the body is just trying to lower the will save of the creature. Are you only interested in ways that make sure there is absolutely no risk involved or is lowering the will save (reducing the risk) enough?

Comment: What method of control are you intending to use?

Comment: Note that Juju Zombie overrides the Dragon type with the Undead Type (which is worse for your party).

Comment: Also, which Linnorm are you looking to raise/subdue? I'm not positive it's important, but it might be.

Comment: @williamporter Why do you say that? Undead have numerous defensive traits... dragons are immune to paralysis and magical sleep (as are undead). It retains all of the other abilities it once had. Granted, any undead is a target of choice for Good divine type people who have abilites that will affect the undead more, but it's not as though they have a choice in that aspect. The thing is already dead.

Comment: @Ifusaso I say it's worse for them, because they seemed to be worried that the dragon type defenses in combination with the defenses given by juju zombie (but not the undead type) were bad. Undead type adds a whole lot more defenses than they seemed to have originally thought of.

Comment: Fair, they do include "Dragon type" in the question. On my first read, I'd kind of read over it and assumed they meant Dragons' inherent difficulty to kill from the dangers of sitting close to them and their solid AC's.

Answer (score 2):

### Stop it before it's created

You could use [manacles](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/goods-and-services/tools-kits#TOC-Manacles), [traps](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/goods-and-services/tools-kits#TOC-Trap-Bear), rope, chains, cages and all sort of mundane and magical contraptions to keep the creature restrained while you use your [Command](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/command-undead/) and/or [Control](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/control-undead/) Undead abilities to gain control. Masterwork manacles have a Strength DC of 28, while Mithril manacles have a DC of 30 and are naturally more durable. A Sawtooth Bear Trap has a Strength DC of 32.

While those aren't checks too difficult for such a creature, they would require multiple checks to escape *all* of them, giving you enough time to apply debuffs and try to control it again.

If the undead is created while already trapped inside a [Crushing Cage Trap](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/traps-hazards-and-special-terrains/traps/crushing-cage-trap-cr-11/), it can't possibly get out of it without help. Though this trap specifically is limited to a 10-foot square area.

Spells like [Shackle](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/shackle/) may also help with that. [Consecrate](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/consecrate/) helps lowering their saves for as long as they remain in the area. While [Prayer](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/prayer/) will apply a penalty to all enemies regardless of their level or stats.

If your caster level is higher than the creature's HD, you could try using [Undead Ward](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/u/undeath-ward/) to prevent it from passing through the designed area. Considering they are Linorm dragons, that is unlikely though. But spells like [Leashed Shackles](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/l/leashed-shackles/), or even [Forcecage](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/forcecage/) have better odds at succeeding.

### Other class's abilities

[Void school wizards](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/arcane-schools/paizo-arcane-schools/elemental-arcane-schools/void-elemental-school/) (*Dragon Empires Primer*) also may reduce saving throws of any creatures with *no saving throw* to resist it. Clerics with the [Madness domain](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric/domains/paizo-domains/madness-domain/) have a similar ability, and those with the [Chaos domain](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric/domains/paizo-domains/chaos-domain/) may force a creature to roll two dice and take the lowest result.

Mesmerists may also apply a penalty to saving throws using their [Hypnotic Stare](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/occult-adventures/occult-classes/mesmerist/) if they also got *Psychic Inception*.

Comment: Note that the evil eye hex doesn't work as the Undead type grants immunity to mind-affecting effects. A mesmerist needs psychic inception to affect them with their hypnotic stare.

Comment: Right, Evil Eye was errata'ed to be a mind-affecting effect.

Comment: [Greater Hide from Undead](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/h/hide-from-undead) offers some protection as well. Attempting to command/control it only grants it another save to see through GHfU, rather than ending the effect, so it would need to succeed on both the save vs command/control and the save vs GHfU to be a threat.

Comment: @ObliviousSage Their concern seems to be both for the party and the world at large (who wants a *rampaging* dracolich anyway?)

Comment: @Ifusaso In my party an escaped rampaging dracolich we had created and failed to control would result in everyone looking at each other and saying, "Well, that's somebody's else's problem. Time to Greater Teleport to another continent and start a new plot line."

Comment: Yeah... but OP seems to think their party would react differently. Not everyone responds the same way (although the fact that this is a plan the party is agreeing to seems to suggest a similar mindset) Specifically, OP says "...we just unleashed in the world something ..." suggesting that simply surviving the shenanigans is a less acceptable outcome

Answer (score 0):

For some of the most common ways, it's kind of too late when it is already dead.  I don't know of any WIS draining abilities that work on corpses.  Though a Wish may be able to lay in a WIS lowering Curse on a corpse.

You could work at it from the other direction.  You can increase the DC by Feats to raise your DC and by using Metamagic to increase the effective spell level of the spell.

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe a Limited Wish that lowers by 7 the dragon's next Will save (against control undead)?
It's one of the few spells I found the crag juju linnorm isn't immune...

Comment: Welcome! You can take the [tour] as an introduction to the site and check the [help] for further guidance.